# Combinatorial subset problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There are n seniors. (a) How many ways can no more than 4 of them get jobs at IBM? (b) How many subsets of size 4 or less are there from a set of size n? (c) How many ways can a subset of the n seniors get jobs a IBM?

(a) I think it's: nC0 + nC1 + nC2 + nC3 + nC4

(b) Isn't this the same as (a)

(c) Not sure

Comment: It is not clear what counts as "a way that three people can get a job at IBM" but under the interpretation that the set of ways is in bijection with the subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ then yes your answer for (a) and (b) are both correct.  For (c), they didn't specify the size of the subset so we can assume they mean a subset of any size.  In that case remember your binomial theorem.  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}=(x+y)^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thanks. I'll try out (c) now.

Comment: @JMoravitz for (c) can I simply answer it as $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$? Because it leads to the last question on the worksheet to give a formula for the number of ways to chose a subset of any size from a set of size n, which I think is $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$

Comment: Both are correct, but $2^n$ is more concise.  That is my interpretation of the question, yes.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you.